# python: найти первое число, кратное N, больше или равное M

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите как наиболее быстро (возможно что-то есть в библиотеках) найти число кратное N и **не меньше** числа M

Делаю так:

```
(n if m % n > 0 else 0) - m % n
```

но есть ли более короткие и быстрые способы чем такое с использованием if?

конечно более коротко можно записать и

```
(n - m % n) if m % n else 0
```

Но везде присутствует этот if :(

Comment: А почему мы итерируемся, чтобы найти? Может можно еще ускорить за счет начальной позиции и шага?

Comment: @Alpensin, не думаю иначе придется вводить лишние массивы, где хранить эти данные - а это накладные расходы, так что эта задача, как я понимаю, должна решаться здесь и сейчас

Comment: Math.ceil(m/n)*n — как-то так на js. В питоне я уверен есть аналогичная функция или оператор

Comment: @AndrewTen точно так же, только math с маленькой буквы

Answer (score 1):

Одно деление:

```
(m + n - 1) - (m + n - 1) % n
```

Деление и умножение:

```
(m + n - 1) // n * n
```